# Adding users to organic groups in CiviCRM

Tags: organic-groups, civicrm

I have a site which uses Organic Groups, specifically with CiviCRM. I want to add a user to a group and I am having issues. The group is marked as closed. I want to how to either

- add a user to a existing group
- open up a closed group

I haven't been able to figure out how to do either of these.

Comment: Are you using the CiviCRM OG Sync module provided with CiviCRM to sync organic group membership with CiviCRM Groups and ACLs?

Answer (score 1):

As @Graham says in [his comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107148/adding-users-to-organic-groups-in-civicrm/136068#comment162858_107148), you may want to use the CiviCRM OG Sync module provided with CiviCRM. If your interest is more in coding this, check out how the module does it at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/blob/7.x-master/modules/civicrm_og_sync/civicrm_og_sync.module.